# Eloquent - Get specific columns from logged-in user

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, orm, eloquent

In Laravel `$user = Auth::user()` returns the currently logged in user. From this user I want to retrieve only a few columns into a key-value array. What are my options?

Example:

```
$user = Auth::user()->fetch('id', 'username', 'email');
```

should give me

```
[
    "id" => 1,
    "username" => "John Doe",
    "email" => "john@doe.example"
]
```

I've searched the Eloquent documentation, but haven't found the function I'm looking for. Have I missed it? Does such a function not exist?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you encountered any error? If yes, what message?

Comment: I'm looking for the method to retrieve the values from the model. The fetch() method doesn't exist.

Comment: Why don't you just write a method that does what you need? Using a framework is not about not writing code anymore...

Comment: Why would I write a new method without knowing if one already exists? Eloquent is a complex library and I'm sure there is a way to do this without writing my own function for it. My question is what my options are in Eloquent to do what I need.

Comment: Have you read through Eloquent API?

Comment: Yes I have and couldn't find the function I need. Otherwise I wouldn't ask.

Comment: So, again, why don't you write the function you need if you could not find it?

Comment: Please, if you are not willing to contribute to this question please refrain from posting comments like these. My question is if there is a way to do this without writing my own function, if there is a way to do it within Eloquent, I think that should be clear by now. Fact that I have scanned the API/documentation and couldn't find it doesn't mean it doesn't exist.

Comment: You are expecting someone to give you a solution without even knowing if it exists.

Comment: I mean: you don't need a complex function that would be optimized if already embeded. Returning an array with 3 properties is rather simple and will not require much CPU.

Comment: OK, you clearly don't understand my question, that's fine. Thank you very much for your help anyway.

Comment: You clearly don't understand my comments.

Comment: You have searched and did not find the function you need. But you still insist to believe it exists and expect someone to have searched better than you. Obviously, I don't understand.

Comment: True, I don't understand you. I'll just wait for somebody who understands my question.

Comment: Or you can just write 2 lines of code to have the function you need. Do as you like.

Comment: No, thanks. I'll wait.

Comment: Smells like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Auth::user()` fetches a user object for you, so you are no longer in Eloquent and can't use Eloquent methods.

There's no method on a model that returns an array of given attributes (reference: https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html), but you can make one on your `User` model, for instance like this:

```
function myData($keys) {
    return array_intersect_key($this->toArray(), array_flip($keys))
}
```

Then you can call it using `$user->myData(['id', 'username', 'keys'])`

Comment: Auth::user() fetches a user object, but that object is still an Eloquent object. Just like you can invoke functions like save(), delete() and others, I would have expected there would be a function to retrieve a set of fields from the object. Guess not. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed... Not like I've encouraged you to write your own.

Comment: I ended up implementing the function you proposed in my BaseModel class (I always use the BaseModel class which extends Eloquent), and renamed it to fetch. Works perfect. Thanks!

Comment: That's true, I meant you're no longer in the Builder so those methods don't work on the single object. I was surprised, too, to find a such method didn't exist, I would have assumed it did, like you did. But I'm glad it helped. :)

Answer (score 5):

If your main objective is to get an array instead of an object, and extra fields in the array are not a problem given that your required fields are there, you could just cast the user model to array:

```
Auth::user()->toArray();
(array) Auth::user();
```

However, if you need the output to only have these 3 properties - you have to do a little bit of extra coding. What I would propose is to create a property in User model that contains a list of publicly exposed fields. Then override toArray() method (or create another method) that only returns fields from the list.

Comment: Thanks. If you are building a query in Eloquent you can use the select() method to filter the fields you want to fetch. So, after fetching a single row there is no way to do the equivalent that the select() method does? And by the way, yes, I do care about the extra fields, as it's an API I'm building and don't want to expose more fields than necessary.

Comment: @Basaa after it's fetched - no, I don't think there is a way. second method is kind of perfect in your case - every model needs to have a pre-defined list of public properties

Comment: Hmm. Very interesting, and kind of bizarre that such a method doesn't exist I think. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @Basaa it's not really bizarre :) choosing appropriate fields is the responsibility of presentation layer (or view), Eloquent shouldn't care about it :)